# How to run D3 Directed Graph Editor code in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347#app.js

I want to run this code with react.js

But I don't know the correct principle.

I want to see index.html , App.js / d3code.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Graph` React component to envelope the D3 code in your sample. See it's working in the snippet:

```js
const {useEffect, useRef} = React;

const render = (width, height, svgHandle) => {
    
const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const svg = d3.select(svgHandle)
  .on('contextmenu', () => { d3.event.preventDefault(); })

const nodes = [
  { id: 0, reflexive: false },
  { id: 1, reflexive: true },
  { id: 2, reflexive: false }
];
let lastNodeId = 2;
const links = [
  { source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1], left: false, right: true },
  { source: nodes[1], target: nodes[2], left: false, right: true }
];

// init D3 force layout
const force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d) => d.id).distance(150))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .on('tick', tick);

// init D3 drag support
const drag = d3.drag()
  // Mac Firefox doesn't distinguish between left/right click when Ctrl is held... 
  .filter(() => d3.event.button === 0 || d3.event.button === 2)
  .on('start', (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();

    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  })
  .on('drag', (d) => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  })
  .on('end', (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);

    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  });

// define arrow markers for graph links
svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 6)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'start-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 4)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M10,-5L0,0L10,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

// line displayed when dragging new nodes
const dragLine = svg.append('svg:path')
  .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
  .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0');

// handles to link and node element groups
let path = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path');
let circle = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

// mouse event vars
let selectedNode = null;
let selectedLink = null;
let mousedownLink = null;
let mousedownNode = null;
let mouseupNode = null;

function resetMouseVars() {
  mousedownNode = null;
  mouseupNode = null;
  mousedownLink = null;
}

// update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
function tick() {
  // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
  path.attr('d', (d) => {
    const deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    const deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    const normX = deltaX / dist;
    const normY = deltaY / dist;
    const sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12;
    const targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12;
    const sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX);
    const sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);
    const targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
    const targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

    return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
  });

  circle.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
}

// update graph (called when needed)
function restart() {
  // path (link) group
  path = path.data(links);

  // update existing links
  path.classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '');

  // remove old links
  path.exit().remove();

  // add new links
  path = path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '')
    .on('mousedown', (d) => {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select link
      mousedownLink = d;
      selectedLink = (mousedownLink === selectedLink) ? null : mousedownLink;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    })
    .merge(path);

  // circle (node) group
  // NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
  circle = circle.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

  // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
  circle.selectAll('circle')
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive);

  // remove old nodes
  circle.exit().remove();

  // add new nodes
  const g = circle.enter().append('svg:g');

  g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 12)
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .style('stroke', (d) => d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString())
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive)
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // enlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
    })
    .on('mousedown', (d) => {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select node
      mousedownNode = d;
      selectedNode = (mousedownNode === selectedNode) ? null : mousedownNode;
      selectedLink = null;

      // reposition drag line
      dragLine
        .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
        .classed('hidden', false)
        .attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}`);

      restart();
    })
    .on('mouseup', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode) return;

      // needed by FF
      dragLine
        .classed('hidden', true)
        .style('marker-end', '');

      // check for drag-to-self
      mouseupNode = d;
      if (mouseupNode === mousedownNode) {
        resetMouseVars();
        return;
      }

      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');

      // add link to graph (update if exists)
      // NB: links are strictly source < target; arrows separately specified by booleans
      const isRight = mousedownNode.id < mouseupNode.id;
      const source = isRight ? mousedownNode : mouseupNode;
      const target = isRight ? mouseupNode : mousedownNode;

      const link = links.filter((l) => l.source === source && l.target === target)[0];
      if (link) {
        link[isRight ? 'right' : 'left'] = true;
      } else {
        links.push({ source, target, left: !isRight, right: isRight });
      }

      // select new link
      selectedLink = link;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    });

  // show node IDs
  g.append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'id')
    .text((d) => d.id);

  circle = g.merge(circle);

  // set the graph in motion
  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .force('link').links(links);

  force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
}

function mousedown() {
  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', true);

  if (d3.event.ctrlKey || mousedownNode || mousedownLink) return;

  // insert new node at point
  const point = d3.mouse(this);
  const node = { id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false, x: point[0], y: point[1] };
  nodes.push(node);

  restart();
}

function mousemove() {
  if (!mousedownNode) return;

  // update drag line
  dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${d3.mouse(this)[0]},${d3.mouse(this)[1]}`);
}

function mouseup() {
  if (mousedownNode) {
    // hide drag line
    dragLine
      .classed('hidden', true)
      .style('marker-end', '');
  }

  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', false);

  // clear mouse event vars
  resetMouseVars();
}

function spliceLinksForNode(node) {
  const toSplice = links.filter((l) => l.source === node || l.target === node);
  for (const l of toSplice) {
    links.splice(links.indexOf(l), 1);
  }
}

// only respond once per keydown
let lastKeyDown = -1;

function keydown() {
  d3.event.preventDefault();

  if (lastKeyDown !== -1) return;
  lastKeyDown = d3.event.keyCode;

  // ctrl
  if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.call(drag);
    svg.classed('ctrl', true);
    return;
  }

  if (!selectedNode && !selectedLink) return;

  switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
    case 8: // backspace
    case 46: // delete
      if (selectedNode) {
        nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(selectedNode), 1);
        spliceLinksForNode(selectedNode);
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        links.splice(links.indexOf(selectedLink), 1);
      }
      selectedLink = null;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
      break;
    case 66: // B
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to both left and right
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 76: // L
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to left only
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = false;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 82: // R
      if (selectedNode) {
        // toggle node reflexivity
        selectedNode.reflexive = !selectedNode.reflexive;
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to right only
        selectedLink.left = false;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
  }
}

function keyup() {
  lastKeyDown = -1;

  // ctrl
  if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.on('.drag', null);
    svg.classed('ctrl', false);
  }
}

// app starts here
svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
  .on('mousemove', mousemove)
  .on('mouseup', mouseup);
d3.select(window)
  .on('keydown', keydown)
  .on('keyup', keyup);
restart();
}


const Graph = ({width, height}) => {
  const svgRef = useRef(null)
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (svgRef.current) {
      render(width, height, svgRef.current);
    }
  }, [svgRef]);
   
  return (
    <svg ref={svgRef} width={width} height={height} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Graph width={500} height={300} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #FFF;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

path.link.selected {
  stroke-dasharray: 10,2;
}

path.link.dragline {
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link.hidden {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

circle.node {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle.node.reflexive {
  stroke: #000 !important;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.id {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

Comment: 'd3' is not defined

Comment: Add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js">`

Comment: ... or `import * as d3 from 'd3'`

Comment: 'event' is not exported from 'd3' (imported as 'd3').

Comment: Which version of D3 you use?

Comment: Make sure you have D3 V5 or earlier, your sample (http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347#app.js) is written with D3 V5 and will not work with V6 or V7

Comment: <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
I use CDN at index.html

Comment: If you use V5, `d3.event` should be OK